# d3 slider package property slider does not exist on type 'typesof d3'

Tags: typescript, d3.js, npm, npm-install, c3.js

i want to use d3 slider on my d3 chart in angular 2.for this purpose i installed the d3slider package by using following command: npm install --save @types/d3.slider
But when i tried to access d3 slider's method "d3.slider()" i got an error of
"property slider does not exist on type 'types of d3' ". can anybody tell me where did i went wrong or what could be the possible issue ?I'm using version 4.8.0 of d3 while version of d3 slider is 0.0.4 which i believe are the latest versions.also if anybody used d3slider chart in typescript;please do share your code.may be it could solve problem for me.
PS:- last two lines are just to fulfill requirement of stackoverflow they believe i didn't explain the problem correctly :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[d3-slider](https://github.com/MasterMaps/d3-slider) isn't compatible with d3v4, it use d3v3.

`d3.drag` does most of tricky bits of making a slider, see this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6452972).

Comment: Thanks @Adam i jumped back to previous version of d3 and it did work for me but now d3 is not recognizing .tick method...this is what i'm trying to do

var slider = d3.slider().min(0).max(10).ticks(10).showRange(true).value(6);

Comment: Look at the examples - http://thematicmapping.org/playground/d3/d3.slider/ - `d3.slider().steps` exists, but to set the ticks you need to pass in an axis `d3.slider().axis( d3.svg.axis().orient("top").ticks(6) )`